# Synchronize playback of audio to a timer using NAudio

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio

I want to synchronize the playback of a song to a timer so that I can keep the beats of a song in sync with things rendered on the screen. Any way of accomplishing this using NAudio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several out the output devices in NAudio support the `IWavePosition` interface, which gives a more accurate indication of where the soundcard is currently up to in the buffer it is playing. Usually this is reported in terms of number of bytes that have been played since playback started - so it does not necessarily correspond to the position within the file you are playing or within a song. So if you use this you will need to keep track of when you started playing.

Usually you would keep the things rendered on screen synchronized to the audio playback position, rather than the other way round.